# Function that visually looks smooth but is not

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, functions

I am wondering how closely our intuition for "smooth" aligns with the mathematical definition of smooth. To that end I was wondering if there is any function that looks "smooth" (i.e. could reasonably be called "smooth" by even a non-mathematical person at any scale) but is not infinitely differentiable (smooth).

Comment: "Visually smooth" to me is closer to $C^1$.  e.g. $f(x) = \begin{cases} x^2, x \ge 0 \\ 0, x < 0 \end{cases}$ is visually smooth but not $C^2$.

Comment: You can also have the reverse problem, where a function is technically $C^\infty$ but the derivatives are *quantitatively* large. For example, $\sin(1/x)$ on $[\epsilon,\pi]$ for $0<\epsilon \ll 1$. Sobolev space theory (and its refinements like Besov space theory etc.) is really good at quantifying this issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For instance, $f(x) = |x|^3$ looks smooth but has no 3rd derivative.